# What's the expected delay between action and a hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash

I know, I know, caching. I just wanted to ask a canonical question to direct all these "why no hat yet?" here.

So, what's the expected delay between doing something and getting hat for it?

Comment: Check this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159136/winter-bash-hats-delay

Answer (score 1):

As answered in linked last year general Stack Overflow post:

1. Most of hats will be awarded in minutes
2. More calculation-intensive hats will be awarded up to 24 hours

Hats are just a badges you can wear, so delay for them is similar to delay for badges, it's the same mechanism.